# Swiper.js pagination custom bullet won't click to move to next slide

Tags: javascript, html, angular, swiper.js

I can't get the custom bullets to slide when clicked from swiper.js.

Here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1psn6v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I've added the config property

> 'clickable: true'

Here is my swiper code code

```js
private pagination: SwiperPaginationInterface = {
  el: '.swiper-pagination',
  type: 'bullets',
  clickable: true,
  renderBullet: function(index, className) {
    return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index === 0 ? 'info ' : 'students') + '</span>';
  },
};
config: SwiperConfigInterface = {
  observer: true,
  observeParents: true,
  observeSlideChildren: true,
  direction: 'horizontal',
  threshold: 50,
  spaceBetween: 0,
  slidesPerView: 1,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  pagination: this.pagination,
  navigation: true,
  // width: 200,
  // setWrapperSize: true,
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you can't click on them due to `pointer-events: none` css rule provided by the author of this Angular library:

```
swiper>.swiper.s-wrapper .swiper-pagination {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

The solution is to open it for any events:

```
:host >>> .swiper-pagination {
  pointer-events: all !important;
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xnfmat?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

There is also [a similar issue](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-swiper-wrapper/issues/267) in github

Comment: thank you for the help. I looked for this but couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 13):

For me this worked:

```
public config: SwiperOptions = {
  pagination: {
   el: '.swiper-pagination',
   clickable: true
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks man, i actually wrote a solution for this before i decided to search (omg) 